# Finding which integrals are equal to the given triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Which of the integrals are equal to

$$\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y} f(x,y,z) dz dy dx$$

a) $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{y} f(x,y,z) dz dy dx$

b) $\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y} f(x,y,z) dx dy dz$

c) $\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{z}^{2} f(x,y,z) dy dz dx$

d) $\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{z} f(x,y,z) dy dz dx$

I know that

$0\leq z\leq y$

$0\leq y \leq 2$

$0 \leq x \leq 3$

Putting it together I get $0\leq z \leq y \leq 2$ but I don't really know what to do from here.

Since I see that $z\leq y \leq 2$ I'm inclined to thing that the answers are (c) and (d)? Are both of them correct or is it either c) or d)?

Comment: Only one of them: double-check (d), I for that I see $0 \leq y \leq z,$ which isn't the same

Comment: ahh yes that makes sense. Is my justification for picking answer choice (c) correct? It seems almost too simple